# how to make a character move in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, maze

So I'm trying to make a maze game in c++. The code below is what I have so far, but I'm looking to make a character in the game able to move using the arrow keys.

Should I be using a getch() command, a ReadInputConsole() command? I've been doing lots of research but it's all very unclear.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void maze1();
void maze2();
void welcome();

char ch;

int main()
{
    int enter;

   welcome();

    cin >> enter;

    if (enter == 1)
    {
      system("CLS"); // clear screen
      maze1();
    } 

   system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void welcome()
{
   cout << " Welcome to my Maze Game!\n\n";
    cout << "In order to win this game, you must make your\n";
    cout << " way through the maze and find the O. \n";
    cout << " Try to get the best time you can to be number 1!\n\n";
    cout << " Warning! Don't touch the walls or you will \n";
    cout << " lose points!\n ";
    cout << " Goodluck and have fun!\n\n\n\n";
    cout << " Press 1 to begin";


} 

void maze1 ()
{
    int begin;

    do // do-while loop starts
    {

    cin >> begin; // take in input

        if(begin == 1) // temporary option to check for next screen
            {

                ifstream fin;
                fin.open("lvl1.txt");

                char ch;

                while (!fin.eof())
                 {
                   fin.get(ch);
                   cout << ch;
                 }

                  fin.close();
             }
          else
            {
                cout << "Sorry, you entered the wrong key.";
             }

        }
    while( begin !=1); // condition of do-while loop

}

void maze2 ()
{
  ifstream fin;
    fin.open("lvl2.txt");

        char ch;

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
      fin.get(ch);
      cout << ch;
    }

    fin.close();
}
```

Comment: maybe [`std::cin.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)?

Answer (score 1):

How about using the W,A,S,D keys like some popular games do for movement? Just like you have in your post, you can use something like

```
std::cin >> key;
```

and just look and see if you get any of the WASD keys.

Your program flow (actually playing the maze) does not seem complete. Also, I cannot see how your maze is actually represented in memory. I can suggest a reasonable algorithm to help you out:

```
load the maze from a file and store the data in a 2-dimensional grid

while playing the maze is in progress
    display the maze
    wait for user input
    attempt the move based on the input
        handle out of bounds case
        handle colliding into a wall case
        handle reaching the goal case
        handle updating grid to the next position
```

Here is a complete program that implements the above algorithm. This was compiled using C++11. I am not a windows developer but I think recent VC++ can support all of the included features.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class Maze {
public:
  void load(std::string&& mazeFilePath);

  void run();

private:
  using Grid = std::vector<std::string>;

  enum class MoveDirection {
    UP,
    DOWN,
    RIGHT,
    LEFT
  };

  enum class MoveResult {
    OK,
    OUT_OF_BOUNDS,
    COLLISION,
    GOAL
  };

  struct Position {
    int row;
    int col;
  };

  void display() const;

  MoveResult movePlayer(MoveDirection direction);

  Grid m_grid;
  Position m_playerPosition;
  Position m_goalPosition;

};

void Maze::load(std::string&& mazeFilePath) {
  m_grid.clear();

  std::ifstream mazeFileStream(mazeFilePath); //todo - readonly flag

  int currentRow = 0;

  for (std::string line; std::getline(mazeFileStream, line);) {
    int currentCol = 0;

    std::string row;

    std::copy_if(std::begin(line), std::end(line), std::back_inserter(row), [&](decltype(row)::value_type c) {
      switch (c) {
        case 'i':
          m_playerPosition.row = currentRow;
          m_playerPosition.col = currentCol;
          break;
        case 'g':
          m_goalPosition.row = currentRow;
          m_goalPosition.col = currentCol;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      ++currentCol;

      return true;
    });

    m_grid.emplace_back(std::move(row));

    ++currentRow;
  }
}

void Maze::display() const {
  std::copy(std::begin(m_grid), std::end(m_grid), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}

void Maze::run() {
  bool running = true;

  char key;

  while (running) {
    display();

    MoveResult moveResult;

    std::cin >> key;

    switch (key) {
      case 'w':
        moveResult = movePlayer(MoveDirection::UP);
        break;
      case 'a':
        moveResult = movePlayer(MoveDirection::LEFT);
        break;
      case 's':
        moveResult = movePlayer(MoveDirection::DOWN);
        break;
      case 'd':
        moveResult = movePlayer(MoveDirection::RIGHT);
        break;
      default:
        std::cerr << "Please use WASD keys to move player" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    switch (moveResult) {
      case MoveResult::OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
        running = false;
        std::cout << "failure (out of bounds) - game over" << std::endl;
        break;
      case MoveResult::COLLISION:
        running = false;
        std::cout << "failure (collision) - game over" << std::endl;
        break;
      case MoveResult::GOAL:
        running = false;
        std::cout << "success - game over" << std::endl;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}

Maze::MoveResult Maze::movePlayer(Maze::MoveDirection direction) {
  Position previousPlayerPosition = m_playerPosition;

  switch (direction) {
    case MoveDirection::UP:
      m_playerPosition.row -= 1;
      break;
    case MoveDirection::LEFT:
      m_playerPosition.col -= 1;
      break;
    case MoveDirection::DOWN:
      m_playerPosition.row += 1;
      break;
    case MoveDirection::RIGHT:
      m_playerPosition.col += 1;
  }

  //check bounds
  try {
    m_grid.at(m_playerPosition.row).at(m_playerPosition.col);
  }
  catch (const std::out_of_range exc) {
    return MoveResult::OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
  }

  //check collision
  if (m_grid[m_playerPosition.row][m_playerPosition.col] == 'x') {
    return MoveResult::COLLISION;
  }
  //check goal
  else if (m_grid[m_playerPosition.row][m_playerPosition.col] == 'g') {
    return MoveResult::GOAL;
  }

  m_grid[previousPlayerPosition.row][previousPlayerPosition.col] = ' ';
  m_grid[m_playerPosition.row][m_playerPosition.col] = 'i';

  return MoveResult::OK;
}

int main() {
  auto maze = std::unique_ptr<Maze>(new Maze);
  maze->load("maze1.txt");
  maze->run();
}
```

The sample map file I used looks like this:

```
xxxgx
xx  x
xx xx
x  xx
xixxx
```

Comment: are you sure writing a whole program for the OP is a good idea?

Comment: The OP can use her own discretion.

Comment: Yes it's a Q&A site. It is possible we have different interpretations of the question. The title is asking how to move a character in a maze and the question body is asking about reading characters from the console. I believe I addressed both.